# Voltar à região da pagina onde estava quando submeter o formulário (JSF 1.2)?

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, rich-faces, java-ee-6

Tenho uma página `jsf` com 2 forms tipo mestre/detalhe.
Como fazer com que após a submissão do form detalhe o bean consiga direcionar para a região da página onde encontra-se o detalhe?
Estou usando  `jsf` 1.2 e  `Richfaces` 3.3.3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032825/how-to-make-a-redirection-in-jsf Da uma olhada nesse topico pode te ajudar

Comment: Guerra, valeu! Vou analisar estas respostas, acho que vai me ajudar muito. Abraços e obrigado.